# Using an sql query result as a search term for a new sql statement

Tags: php, mysql

So I am trying to use a result from an SQL search `$search_course` and then having that as the `WHERE LIKE` part of the next statement `$Search_Module`.

once the `$Search_Module` query has finished I would like the results to be in a list which I know should be coded correctly.

I have tried the following code but the search returns no values;

Any help with this would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
        $search_course = "
    SELECT title, id, wyl, overview, module, course, careers
    FROM course
    LEFT JOIN cm
    ON course.id=cm.course
    WHERE id LIKE '%".$_POST['submitcourseselection']."%'";

    $result = $mysqli->query($search_course) or die($mysqli->error);
    $display_course = $result->fetch_assoc();

    //Searches the module table in the DB for modules within the course
    $Search_Module = "
    SELECT id, title, level, credits
    FROM module
    WHERE id LIKE '".$search_course['module']."'";

    $M_Results = $mysqli->query($Search_Module) or die($mysqli->error);


    $ModuleList = '';
    while ($MResults = $M_Results->fetch_assoc()) {
        $ID = $MResults['id'];
        $Title = $MResults['title'];
        $Level = $MResults['level'];
        $Credits = $MResults['credits'];
        $ModuleList.='<div><h2>'.$Title.'</h2></div>'; 
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the tables structure? You should really use a JOIN here.

Comment: in what form do you need the table structure @MeesKluivers

Comment: It does not have to be `LIKE` how would I implement `=?` ?

Comment: I don't see why you are doing what you are currently doing. Why not use a join and then do something like: SELECT * FROM course JOIN module ON course.id = model.id WHERE module.id LIKE etc..

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need LIKE in your second query and you can do all by one query.

```
    $search_course = "
        SELECT id, title, level, credits
        FROM module
        WHERE id IN (SELECT module
        FROM course
        LEFT JOIN cm
        ON course.id=cm.course
        WHERE id LIKE '%".$_POST['submitcourseselection']."%'")";
```

Comment: This does retrieve the information i was looking for however i need the first query aswell as it relates to other information displayed on the page. Is there a way to include this aswell?

Answer (score 0):

in your where clause `WHERE id LIKE '".$search_course['module']."'";`, you are referencing an array location of a string `$search_course`, which is your SQL statement.

I think you meant to reference your result array `$display_course`, so try this:

```
$search_course = "
SELECT title, id, wyl, overview, module, course, careers
FROM course
LEFT JOIN cm
ON course.id=cm.course
WHERE id LIKE '%".$_POST['submitcourseselection']."%'";

$result = $mysqli->query($search_course) or die($mysqli->error);
$display_course = $result->fetch_assoc();

//Searches the module table in the DB for modules within the course
$Search_Module = "
SELECT id, title, level, credits
FROM module
WHERE id LIKE '".$display_course['module']."'";

$M_Results = $mysqli->query($Search_Module) or die($mysqli->error);


$ModuleList = '';
while ($MResults = $M_Results->fetch_assoc()) {
    $ID = $MResults['id'];
    $Title = $MResults['title'];
    $Level = $MResults['level'];
    $Credits = $MResults['credits'];
    $ModuleList.='<div><h2>'.$Title.'</h2></div>'; 
}
```

Comment: I have tried this also but cant get the results I am after. I am trying to figure out how to encorporate Mojtaba's answer into the second sql query `$search_module` but am not sure how to do so